# Handling duplicate values in Business Intelligence Studio Cube dimensions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, business-intelligence, dimensions, olap-cube

I have a Cube dimension which has a relationship between tier and market.

[image]

They are contained in the same table, with structure id, tier, market. However, when I create the dimension, it's showing a row in member properties for EACH row in the table. Is there any way to construct this again so that it becomes :
Tier1
Tier2
Tier3
with the markets listed underneath each relevant tier when I expand it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found the issue. The above table had 3 columns: id, tier, market. When BIS automatically created the dimension, it added a one-one relationship.
Delete the dimension, creaqte a new dimension using that existing table, set id as the key column, then select the other columns as dimension attributes. Rebuild, redeploy, and process, and the dimension will have a tree structure as required.